# Google Sheets: How to count array entries in current weeknum?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has data in one column (H2:H500) and dates in another column (F2:F500). I would like a sum of the total number in the past work week (Monday-Friday). I'm not sure if I need to use `=CountIfs` or what. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
=COUNTIFS(F2:F500,WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1),H2:H500, "<>")
```

...doesn't seem to work. Am I close?

Comment: `COUNTIF` sounds like a good option. Why don,t you go ahead and try it?

Comment: Can you tell me what to use for the past work week in the formula?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Nk43p2Xi1wNOmJmZtbBzyuQ5YEDk9MoVjJcSB_WeIg/edit?usp=sharing  - here is a copy of the sheet. If you could fill in the formula for E2 and E4, that would be excellent! I really appreciate it

Comment: =COUNTIFS(F2:F500,WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1),H2:H500, "<>") doesn't seem to work. Am I close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=COUNTA(QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select Col1 
  where Col2 is not null 
    and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1),3)+7*
           (WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1),3)>3)+7*(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-2),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1),3)+7*
           (WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1),3)>3)+7*(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-2)+4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: THANK YOU!! This was the perfect formula. I truly appreciate your help and hard work. You're the best!